# How to display all the column values of overlapping polygons in leaflet popup with R?

Tags: r, leaflet, sf, rstudio

I have intersected points data with a grid in which I would like to display the name of all the species found in every cell.

Code sample:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet)
library(sf)

data = data.frame(species = c("A","B","C","D","E", "E", "F"), size = c(1,3,2,5,1,2,7), lat = c(43.47, 43.38, 43.78, 43.76,43.72, 43.81,43.778), long = c(2.7,3.42,3.06,3.42,3.25,3.08,3.058))

points = st_as_sf(data, coords = c("long", "lat"))
points<- points %>% st_set_crs(st_crs(CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))) 


grid <- st_make_grid( st_as_sfc( st_bbox( points ) ), n = 25 ) %>% 
  st_cast( "POLYGON" ) %>% st_as_sf()
grid$id <- seq.int(nrow(grid))

grid <- st_transform(grid, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")) 


grid_and_points <-st_join(grid, points)

binpal <- colorBin("OrRd", reverse = FALSE, sum(y$size), 6, na.color = "transparent", pretty = FALSE)


leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addPolygons( data = grid_and_points ,
               weight = 1,
               fillColor = binpal(grid_and_points $size),
               fillOpacity = 0.5,
               popup= ~species) %>%
  addAwesomeMarkers(data = data, popup= ~species)
```

It's a very simple task when there is only one specie in one cell of the grid but I'm facing some issues when there are several species in one cell of the grid since I have as many overlapping polygons as species in the cell. Is there an easy way to display the names of all overlapping polygons in the leaflet popup and fill the color of every grid based on the sum of the species number (size column) ?

I thought about using a function like "aggregate" in order to concatenate the column "species" but I don't know if it is the actual best solution and how to do it...

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed use the aggregate function as suggested here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596515/aggregating-by-unique-identifier-and-concatenating-related-values-into-a-string